# Comperhensive financial data api?

Tags: api

I'm looking for a comprehensive financial data api. It should contain index-data for 5 of the worlds largest stockmarkets. Just closing data, and if possible historic closing data.

I've been looking at yahoo finance, google finance and bloomberg, but none of them seem to contain all the stockmarkets. Any suggestions?

Comment: What data are you looking for? Daily close prices? Historic closes? Or do you need more detail, like intraday updates and/or constituent data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Xignite](http://www.xignite.com/) is worth a look. It is more comprehensive than the free ones you mention but you do have to pay.

There is also [IQFeed](http://www.iqfeed.net/), which is very reasonably priced.